# Error connecting to SQL Server 2008 Express over a LAN

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

We have a VB.NET application which uses SQL Server Express 2008. This application could have any number of users. One user will be the server, so there won't be any problem in connecting (`.\SQlExpress`). But other users have to access the database through LAN, where I couldn't connect. I have given `\SQLExpress` (should I try with the IP address of server?). I get an error. Why?

We are not giving them SSMS, only SQL Server Express.

Code used to connect is VB.NET.

Comment: Welcome, prabal! I've voted to close because this is a question regarding setting up SQL Server, not software development. I have, however, posted an answer.

Comment: Hi, I've also voted to close as the question's not quite right for SO - If you have more questions like this in future, try Server Fault. That said, welcome!

Answer (score 3):

By default, SQL Server express is not configured to allow for connections from other computers. In order to do this, you'll need to access the SQL Server configuration snap-in and enable TCP/IP connections. You'll also need to ensure that the firewall on that computer is configured to allow connections to SQL Server.